# Custom tikz package not compiling

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages

I want to include [this library](https://github.com/HarisIqbal88/PlotNeuralNet) in my document. Using it standalone works fine. But when I include I get an error in the Ball.sty package which looks like this:

```
\ProvidesPackage{Ball}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%This Block can draw small Ball
%Elementwise or reduction operations can be drawn with this
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\tikzset{Ball/.pic={\tikzset{/sphere/.cd,#1}        

\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{\radius*\scale}

\shade[ball color=\fill,opacity=\opacity] (0,0,0) circle (\r);
\draw (0,0,0) circle [radius=\r] node[scale=4*\r] {\logo};

\coordinate (\name-anchor) at ( 0 , 0  , 0) ;
\coordinate (\name-east)   at ( \r, 0  , 0) ;
\coordinate (\name-west)   at (-\r, 0  , 0) ;
\coordinate (\name-north)  at ( 0 , \r , 0) ;
\coordinate (\name-south)  at ( 0 , -\r, 0) ;

\coordinate (\name-southwest)  at ( -0.70710678118 * \r , -0.70710678118 * \r, 0) ;
\coordinate (\name-northeast)  at ( 0.70710678118 * \r , 0.70710678118 * \r, 0) ;

\path (\name-south) + (0,-20pt) coordinate (caption-node) 
edge ["\textcolor{black}{\bf \caption}"'] (caption-node); %Ball caption

},
/sphere/.search also={/tikz},
/sphere/.cd,
radius/.store       in=\radius,
scale/.store        in=\scale,
caption/.store      in=\caption,
name/.store         in=\name,
fill/.store         in=\fill,
logo/.store         in=\logo,
opacity/.store      in=\opacity,
logo=$\Sigma$,
fill=green,
opacity=0.10,
scale=0.2,
radius=0.5,
caption=,
name=,
}
```

The critical lines are `fill/.store         in=\fill,` and `fill=green,`. For some reason I get the error

```
Missing number, treated as zero.

<to be read again> 
                   g
l.55 \newskip\LTleft       \LTleft=\fill

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
```

And some follow up errors, resting upon the first error.

After some hours of debugging I have absolutely no clue what could lead to this error. Maybe someone else has a guess?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not store keys in a macro that coincide with the Ti*k*Z command `\fill`. It is IMHO much better not to store anything in explicit macros, but to use `\pgfkeysvalueof{...}` instead. So you may want to use this for `Ball.sty`.

```
\ProvidesPackage{Ball}
\tikzset{Ball/.pic={\tikzset{/sphere/.cd,#1}        
\def\skv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/sphere/##1}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{\skv{radius}*\skv{scale}}

\shade[ball color=\skv{fill},opacity=\skv{opacity}] (0,0,0) circle (\r);
\draw (0,0,0) circle [radius=\r] node[scale=4*\r] {\skv{logo}};

\coordinate (\skv{name}-anchor) at ( 0 , 0  , 0) ;
\coordinate (\skv{name}-east)   at ( \r, 0  , 0) ;
\coordinate (\skv{name}-west)   at (-\r, 0  , 0) ;
\coordinate (\skv{name}-north)  at ( 0 , \r , 0) ;
\coordinate (\skv{name}-south)  at ( 0 , -\r, 0) ;

\coordinate (\skv{name}-southwest)  at ( -0.70710678118 * \r , -0.70710678118 * \r, 0) ;
\coordinate (\skv{name}-northeast)  at ( 0.70710678118 * \r , 0.70710678118 * \r, 0) ;

\path (\skv{name}-south) + (0,-20pt) coordinate (caption-node) 
edge ["\textcolor{black}{\bfseries\skv{caption}}"'] (caption-node); %Ball caption

},
/sphere/.search also={/tikz},
/sphere/.cd,
radius/.initial=0.5,
scale/.initial=0.2,
caption/.initial={},
name/.initial={},
fill/.initial=green,
logo/.initial={$\Sigma$},
opacity/.initial=0.1}
\endinput
```

As you can see, it works:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{Ball/.pic={\tikzset{/sphere/.cd,#1}        
\def\skv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/sphere/##1}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{\skv{radius}*\skv{scale}}

\shade[ball color=\skv{fill},opacity=\skv{opacity}] (0,0,0) circle (\r);
\draw (0,0,0) circle [radius=\r] node[scale=4*\r] {\skv{logo}};

\coordinate (\skv{name}-anchor) at ( 0 , 0  , 0) ;
\coordinate (\skv{name}-east)   at ( \r, 0  , 0) ;
\coordinate (\skv{name}-west)   at (-\r, 0  , 0) ;
\coordinate (\skv{name}-north)  at ( 0 , \r , 0) ;
\coordinate (\skv{name}-south)  at ( 0 , -\r, 0) ;

\coordinate (\skv{name}-southwest)  at ( -0.70710678118 * \r , -0.70710678118 * \r, 0) ;
\coordinate (\skv{name}-northeast)  at ( 0.70710678118 * \r , 0.70710678118 * \r, 0) ;

\path (\skv{name}-south) + (0,-20pt) coordinate (caption-node) 
edge ["\textcolor{black}{\bfseries\skv{caption}}"'] (caption-node); %Ball caption

},
/sphere/.search also={/tikz},
/sphere/.cd,
radius/.initial=0.5,
scale/.initial=0.2,
caption/.initial={},
name/.initial={},
fill/.initial=green,
logo/.initial={$\Sigma$},
opacity/.initial=0.1}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \path (0,0,0) pic{Ball} (3,0,0) pic{Ball={fill=blue,radius=4}}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you say why it is better not to store things in macros (but all right to `\def` a macro to retrieve things stored in keys)? I've never got the hang of PGF keys and always store things in macros, though I've heard before it is better not to do this. (Basically, I understand this way of doing it, whereas it never seems to work quite as I expect otherwise.)

Comment: @cfr I think this example shows why you may not want to use macros, at least not macros which are called `\fill` or `\caption`. If you store these things in pgf keys, they will end up also being macros internally, but first of all you have only one of them, and then due to the directory structure of pgf you can be almost sure that they do not collide with macros others use, unless of course some one else calls their directory `sphere` and has a key `radius` under it. Still better than just using `\radius` IMHO.

Comment: Yes, but is there any other reason? The naming issue is not fundamentally different from that in other contexts. (I would never use `\fill` or `\caption` or `\radius`. I might use `\llenwi` or `\testun` or `\cath@llenwi`. Usually something like the latter in a library, though it does depend.)

Comment: @cfr To me this is the most important reason. You can create rather unique names which may not be accidentally overwritten by others. Also `caption/.initial={},` is shorter than `caption/.store in=\mycaption,caption={},`. It would be good to know for which one the performance is better.

Comment: I've just never had any luck understanding keys in a way which got `.initial` to work, so I've tended to use macros. (And I'm pretty paranoid about names. Just so long as Ti*k*Z doesn't get a Welsh maintainer. Then I'll be screwed. Though `\cath@llenwi` - I'd have to be very unlucky for something like that to backfire.)

Comment: @cfr Yes, of course, `\makeatletter` serves a similar purpose. However, to retrieve `\cath@llenwi` you again need `\makeatletter` whereas `\pgfkeysvalueof{/curious/cat}` doesn't, and is also hard to overwrite.

Comment: Yes, but I'm pretty much always retrieving in the library code. Anyway, you don't need a catcode change to use `@` in a `tikzpicture`.

Comment: @cfr Probably I am misunderstanding, but `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\makeatletter 
\def\cath@llenwi{7}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\cath@llenwi
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}` does not work. What do you mean by "you don't need a catcode change to use `@` in a `tikzpicture`"?

Comment: `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{tikz}\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[annus/horriblus/.store in=\annus@horriblus, annus/horriblus=horror]
  \node {\annus@horriblus};
\end{tikzpicture}\end{document}`

Comment: @cfr Indeed. Very interesting: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter 
\def\cath@llenwi{7}
\makeatother
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[annus/horriblus/.store in=\annus@horriblus, annus/horriblus=horror]
 \node {\annus@horriblus}; 
 \show\annus@horriblus
 \show\cath@llenwi
\makeatletter 
\show\cath@llenwi
\makeatother
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}` `> \annus=macro:
@horriblus->horror.`. I did not know this.

Comment: If you use another macro that coincides up to `@` it does no longer seem to work: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[annus/horriblus/.store in=\annus@horriblus, 
annus/horriblus=horror,
annus/stupidus/.store in=\annus@stupidus, 
annus/stupidus=stupidus
]
 \node {\annus@horriblus}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: Maybe it just ignores the text then. I generally use this in libraries. (And actually, I seem to be using `y` more than `@`, though I'm using both.) Interesting it doesn't complain ....